# Changing lower limit of integral of exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

From Wikipedia's [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions) of integrals of exponential functions we see that

$$
\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-ax^b}dx = \frac{1}{b}a^{-\frac{n+1}{b}}\Gamma[(n+1)/b]
$$

Is there a way to evaluate this integral with a lower limit $K>0$?

Comment: Yes, it would be in terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: Thanks @NinadMunshi - I can't get it to match with the incomplete gamma function though. You are welcome to elaborate in an answer in case I am missing something, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the incomplete Gamma function is

$$\Gamma(s,z) = \int_s^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$

Using the substitution $t = ax^b$ gets you the same result in the post, integrand, prefactor and all. The only thing that changes is the lower bound goes from $K \mapsto aK^b$ which means the answer is just simply

$$
\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-ax^b}dx = \frac{1}{b}a^{-\frac{n+1}{b}}\Gamma\left(aK^b,\frac{n+1}{b}\right)
$$

Fun fact, all I did was copy paste your equation and inserted the new argument.